# Using a datetime function on a column using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to calculate the difference (in seconds) between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and a DATETIME column. I've just used `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, someColumnName)` in SQL, but I am having trouble doing this using Sequelize.

I've tried doing something like this, but I can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
  Project
    .findAll({
      include: [Note, Link],
      attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'SECOND', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'createdAt'), 'diff']
      ]
    })
    .then(res.send.bind(res));
```

Is there a way of adding using a function as an attribute using Sequelize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sequelize.col to mark the column (otherwise it will be escaped as a string)

```
sequelize.fn('TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'SECOND', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', sequelize.col('createdAt'))
```

Comment: it is saying unknown columns for the TIMESTAMPDIFF and SECOND for me